# Iterate over numpy array in a specific order based on values

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I want to iterate over a numpy array starting at the index of the highest value working through to the lowest value

```
import numpy as np #imports numpy package

elevation_array = np.random.rand(5,5) #creates a random array 5 by 5

print elevation_array # prints the array out

ravel_array = np.ravel(elevation_array)
sorted_array_x = np.argsort(ravel_array)
sorted_array_y = np.argsort(sorted_array_x)

sorted_array = sorted_array_y.reshape(elevation_array.shape)

for index, rank in np.ndenumerate(sorted_array):
    print index, rank
```

I want it to print out:

index of the highest value
index of the next highest value
index of the next highest value etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

>>> a = np.array([[2, 7], [1, 4]])
array([[2, 7],
       [1, 4]])

>>> sorted(np.ndenumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[((0, 1), 7), 
 ((1, 1), 4), 
 ((0, 0), 2), 
 ((1, 0), 1)]
```

you can iterate this list if you so wish. Essentially I am telling the function `sorted` to order the elements of `np.ndenumerate(a)` according to the key `itemgetter(1)`. This function `itemgetter` gets the second (index 1) element from the tuples `((0, 1), 7), ((1, 1), 4),` ... (i.e the values) generated by `np.ndenumerate(a)`.

Comment: Hi elyase and dkar thanks. I was wondering could you explain this a little bit for me? I am still very new to numpy and python.

Comment: Thanks elyase thats great!

Answer (score 3):

If you want numpy doing the heavy lifting, you can do something like this:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(100, 100)
>>> sort_idx = np.argsort(a, axis=None)
>>> np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(sort_idx[::-1], a.shape))
array([[13, 62],
       [26, 77],
       [81,  4],
       ..., 
       [83, 40],
       [17, 34],
       [54, 91]], dtype=int64)
```

You first get an index that sorts the whole array, and then convert that flat index into pairs of indices with [`np.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html). The call to `np.column_stack` simply joins the two arrays of coordinates into a single one, and could be replaced by the Python `zip(*np.unravel_index(sort_idx[::-1], a.shape))` to get a list of tuples instead of an array.